# Format detection meta tag with content not working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-chrome, meta-tags

I'm using the following tag in header of my HTML:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no" />
```

However in Android Chrome the tap on address opens up Google Maps app with the address pre-loaded. This is not the behavior in iOS Chrome. The address format I'm using to display on my page is:

> 1 Hacker Way, Menlo Park, CA 94025